# Automatically mount and copy files to USB drive [Raspbian Buster Lite, headless]

Tags: linux, usb, mount, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am new to Linux and programming. My question is similar to this [one](https://superuser.com/questions/1329938/automatically-copy-files-to-hundreds-of-usb-flash-drives) but I am running a Raspberry Pi 4 headless with no desktop [buster lite] which does seem to automount the usb drives.  I haven't found a non-janky way to automatically mount USB new drives so that their path will be predictable.  This RPi4 has a sensor and I want it to automatically save the sensor data onto any thumbdrive that is inserted into it.  I can just periodically unplug the drive and put in a new one, then go back home.  I need to be able to use any fresh USB drive, not just reusing the same few.  The rest of the work I am doing is on python but this function could be carried out separately without python. This solution needs to survive reboots of the pi.

Appreciate everyone's help.  As I am quite new, I'd especially appreciate explanations of what you're recommending.

Comment: I solved part of the problem my using the package usbmount; however, the mounting points it creates (/media/usb0 ... /media/usb7) exist whether or not any USB drive is plugged in. Furthermore, one can actually write to these locations even when no USB is plugged.  If I could fix that, then it would be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Write a script to populate /dev/sdX and mount the usb's (or do other checks)
2. Modify udevd to run your script when a USB drive is attached.

The script can start like this:

```
    for i in $(ls /dev/sd* | awk -F '/'  '{ print $3 }')
    do
            echo "Do stuff like: mkdir /mnt/$i"
    done
```

You can config udev like this. With proper values you will see devices at /dev/usb/NAMEYOUCHOOSE

```
BUS=="usb", ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd[a-z][0-9]*", NAME="%k", RUN+="/usr/local/sbin/YOURSCRIPT"
```

Helpful commands

```
udevadm monitor
```

Plug your devices. Then check their attributes like

```
udevadm info --path /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-4/usb_device/usbdev1.49 --attribute-walk
```

(You have to use different values)

After you write your rules, force udevd re-read them.

```
udevadm control --reload-rules
```

Recconnect your devices. Modify /etc/fstab as you wish.

But I prefer something simpler. Maybe you have /dev/disk/by-label/ So label your media accordingly and modify your fstab.

Comment: Thank you!  I am trying to do this w/o having to precondition the USB devices.  I need to be able to let someone go buy a USB drive from any store and plug it in right away.  Am I interpreting your answer correctly that it doesn't require a pre-known disk label or UUID?

Comment: My bad, check updated answer.

Comment: thanks!  However, it doesn't seem like USB drives are always put onto sda1.  Sometimes its sdb, sdc, etc.

Comment: Weird. Added a bash script to get you starting.

Comment: I hadn't selected as a solution because I am too novice to follow all the steps.  I have tried to learn in the interim but am not there yet.

Comment: Hmmm... it's been two years! For a start, you should check if udev reacts to your USB insertion with `udevadm monitor`. Run the command before the USB insertion. Insert the USB and check for reporting.